# Is there any way to add a class to a JOOMLA PLUGIN

Tags: jquery, html, css, plugins, joomla

I am using Joomla 3.2 with a template which has tendency to hide modules from displaying in mobile and tablet using module suffixes like : **nomobile** and **notablet** So, technically when we add these module suffix's, it's actually adding this to html code :`<div class="nomobile>` or `<div class="notablet">`. Now, i just installed a **SCROLL TO TOP** type plugin and i want to hide it from the mobile site, is there any way to hide that plugin using this `<div class="nomobile>` anywhere?

Comment: I've given you a basic answer below, but would need more information about the "scroll to top" plugin in order to help you hide it.

Comment: can you please specify which plug-in you are using for "SCROLL TO TOP"

Comment: i am using Skyline Scroll To Top plugin : [link] (http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/structure-a-navigation/site-navigation/19772) . There are two files in this plugin folder. One **.php** & other is **.xml** . Source code of the php file : [link] (http://pastebin.com/j6vLFHeF) and the source code of the xml file : [link] (http://pastebin.com/7XsiRdfP)  . Kindly, tell me what exactly to do now!

Answer (score 0):

This will detect the use of that class on the page..

```
if ($(".nomobile").length) {
    // class exists on the page - hide the scroll to top elements
}
else {
    // class does not exist on the page
}
```